# Could entropy be reversed with enough energy?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, entropy, thought-experiment

**Could a vast amount of energy (such as all the energy in the accessible universe) be intentionally used to pull matter in the universe back together, thus reversing entropy?**

(edit: the previous section here questioned vacuum energy as a source, but as discussed below- that energy is not *harnessable.*)

**Expected obstacles:**

- The cosmological constant / inflation rate being faster than the speed of light/gravitational effect (because then what mechanism could possibly catch up to that galaxy at the far end of *stuff*? No amount of energy would help).
- The gravitational force is too weak to exert the necessary force on all particles/fields
- You could maybe succeed at negating some amount of entropy, but never achieve an actual reversal of entropy
- In a strict thermodynamics sense, being "gifted" the energy also technically fails, because the external system is really just an extension of our system, and would bring its own entropy.

Comment: This comes from a thought experiment about a Kardashev type-4 civilization being tasked with ensuring an ultimate big crunch despite the known accelerating inflation. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Wouldn't the nearly endless amount of energy come with a nearly endless amount of entropy of its own?

Comment: That's true. So then that system and our system are really just _the system_, and we're back to the original problem.

Comment: "Infinite energy" is not well-defined within the realm of conventional physics, nor is it clear in what shape or form this "infinite energy" would be availableto be used. Physics cannot answer questions that pose unphysical situations.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I've reworded the question, removed all qft side questions, and sliced almost everything out of the description so it focuses on using a finite amount of energy available in the universe in attempt to reverse entropy inside its own system. Does this resolve the issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** - to an extent.

If you had an unlimited energy reserve you could draw from with a machine, no matter the form, you have effectively a machine that is capable of doing unlimited work. It'd be a perpetual motion machine but without violating energy conservation, because it draws the energy from the infinite reservoir instead of just "making it from nothing".

Thermodynamics does not forbid the reduction of entropy in a system, only without any external work done upon that system. Here, your machine becomes effectively an infinite source of doing external work, thus it can reduce the entropy arbitrarily far.

Basically, your question is very close to the idea of whether the Universe is a "closed system" (i.e. there aren't such "external works" possible upon it) or not. If it is not, then such entropy decreases are possible. The external source will have to increase its entropy, but in the way you've described it, it would have infinite entropy capacity.

The "to an extent" part that I just mentioned is because there is another limit here due to the cosmic expansion, and that is the cosmic event horizon, thanks to general relativity. You cannot influence any events outside this horizon, and that means you also cannot *get* your "work" to them, no matter how much of it you can do. Thus, there will be areas of the Universe you cannot reduce the entropy of: you can only do it for the area within that horizon, about 160 Ym (16 billion light years) in radius.

**ADD**: That said, I see you also talk about "vacuum energy". Vacuum energy, as you've described it, *cannot* be used as such an infinite energy source - for that to be possible, it would have to be that our existing quantum field theories are wrong on this point, because according to them, the vacuum energy is *the lowest one possible* to achieve. Extracting it would require there to be a state with lower energy to represent the results of that extraction, and there aren't any such states.

Of course, those theories could be wrong, but in that circumstance, we cannot describe if this would work (and not, say, cause some sort of catastrophic effect), without knowing *how* they are wrong in that case, i.e. what's "really" going on (or a better model of such, to be more precise), and if one wants to speculate on such, then one has effectively unlimited freedom to imagine anything at all, as it's as "big as a negation".

Comment: Great answer, and good point about the vacuum energy being the universal ground state- you could never "remove" it because then you'd be violating the rule that gives it existence in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Infinities aren't physically real, so I have difficulty even entertaining a thermodynamics question that includes "infinite energy". I really did read your whole question, and I just don't see any modern interpretation of thermodynamics where your idea could be tested.

Could a "very high" amount of energy reverse entropic contributions to thermodynamic systems? Certainly each individual phenomena is time-reversible, so I guess I'll concede its incredibly unlikely but possible for entropic reversal but I mean this isn't relevant to any real universe.

Comment: I would cast my bet on infinities not existing too. And seeing that the ground-state vacuum energy could not actually be removed (because then there'd be _nothing_, violating the Heisenberg principle that suggests it in the first place), I guess a still "uncountably large" amount of gifted energy would have to come from another system, which _was_ following thermodynamics. Which then makes it part of the _whole system_, collapsing the notion of removing entropy from a closed system.